# How to use jdbc with SQL developer

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to connect with my Eclipse program on my database in SQL developer.
I searched on the internet, but there is just one video and it doesn't work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGG_N9Mlgdw

Mine doesn't turn  like in the video.

I know I have to insert the following `jdbc:oracle:thin@myserver:1521/demodb`, but it doesn't work.

I think I have to provide a link between sql developer and eclipse, but I don't know how.

PS:I have an account provided from school to use sql developer.
I can do that, or it doesn't work?

Comment: Have you only installed the SQL Developer or also an Oracle database? Because the SQL Developer is just an tool to connect to an database and does not provide a database itself

Comment: I can't use the server provided for me from school?

Comment: So you can Connect to this server via the SQL Developer? Do you see a error message Ort anything similar?

Comment: Please show the code you used and the error you get.

Comment: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin@myserver:1521/demodb
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at lucurl_cu_baze_de_date.Driver.main(Driver.java:9)

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: The URL should be `jdbc:oracle:thin//@myserver:1521/demodb` not `jdbc:oracle:thin@myserver:1521/demodb`

Answer (score 0):

Find out what your database is and download that corresponding jar file and place it in the lib folder. If you can share what your database is(is it Mysql/sql/Oracle?) and I can share step by step instruction

Comment: So,my University has a partnership with Oracle.They gave us a port,an address and also usename and pasword .

Comment: so get out of eclipse, open sql developer. paste in your jbc url into the advanced connection type dialog. or parse the values and build your own basic connection

Comment: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>                                                    It looks like trying ,but something goes wrong

Comment: if you are able to connect using some other tool, but not through eclipse, kindly check if you have any proxy config and if so, add the same proxy configuration in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Eclipse and Sql developer you can use only Eclipse to connect to the database.

Refer [this](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700344899.html) for configuring your eclipse to connect to different databases.

Using this Database Connections view configuration you can connect to any database MySQL, Orcale, Postgres etc.

Comment: I still get the error invalid url when running this way myConn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin//@192.168.4.65:1521:oradb","user","password")

Comment: did you add the dirver jar file?

Comment: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
....    It looks like it's trying to connect,but something isn't working

Comment: But,i can connect to the server in sql developper .I should try to use tnsping ,given this conditions?

Comment: Are you able to connect to oracle database using any other tool? Just wanted to make sure we have right credentials.

Comment: Yes.I use Oracle server to work for my University projects

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue now. For me it still looks like credentials issue. What you can do is download latest SQL Developer from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html and Create new connection using the details given at http://imgur.com/a/LTjiN